# how to filter sequelize findall based on many to many relationship

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, postgresql, sequelize-typescript

`

```
import { Op } from 'sequelize';
import { ICreateCourseDTO } from '../dto/Course';
import { IGetCourseDTO } from '../dto/Course/GetCourseDTO';
import { Course, Professor, Section, User } from '../database/models';

interface ICourseService {
  get(dto: IGetCourseDTO): Promise<Course[]>;
}

export class CourseService implements ICourseService {
  public create(course: ICreateCourseDTO): Promise<Course> {

    return Course.create(course);
  }

  public get({
    code,
    ids,
    section,
    semesterId,
    relations = [ `sections`, `sections.professor`, `sections.students` ],
    studentId,
  }: IGetCourseDTO): Promise<Course[]> {
    return Course.findAll({
      include: [

        ...relations?.includes(`sections`) ? [
          {
            include: [
              ...relations?.includes(`sections.professor`) ? [{ as: `professor`, model: Professor }] : [],
              ...relations?.includes(`sections.students`) ?
                [
                  {
                    as: `students`,
                    model: User,
                    //       where: { id: studentId },
                  },
                ] : [],
            ],
            model: Section,
          },
        ] : [],

      ],
      where: {
        ...!!ids?.length && { id: { [Op.in]: ids } },
        ...!!code && { code },
        ...!!section && { '$sections.code$': section },
        ...!!semesterId && { '$sections.semester_id$': semesterId },
        ...!!semesterId && { '$sections.students.student_id$': studentId },

      },
    });
  }
}
```

`I have 2 tables:` sections`, and` users`

- They have many-to-many relationships
- There is another table `students_sections`

The relationship between these tables are:

```js
User.belongsToMany(Section, { through: `users_sections` });
Section.belongsToMany(User, { as: `students`, otherKey: `student_id`, through: `students_sections` });
```

I am using a joiner table of `Students_Section` which contains: `id`, `student_id`, and `section_id`.

I am also using alias as `User` to `Students_Section` table

Now I want to find all sections that belong to that specific `student_id`. Can anyone please help me out how I can do that? How can I filter sequelize `findAll` based on many-to-many relationships?

Comment: You need to include the models in your `findAll` e.g. `Section.findAll({ include: [{ model: User }] })`

Comment: Check out this tutorial referring to ["includes"](https://lorenstewart.me/2016/09/12/sequelize-table-associations-joins/#2declaringincludesinouractions).

Comment: Yes, I have included the models in my findAll definition. I have posted my code snippet. please have a look. @Mr.Polywhirl